# How to map MULTIPLE ActiveDirectory Groups to SQL Logins?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, active-directory

**Situation:**

- A Windows user is member in **multiple** AD groups.
- Every AD group is mapped to a SQL Server login.
- Every SQL login is mapped to a database user.
- Every database user has specific roles.

**Question:**

Is it possible that a Windows user is logging into SQL Server (using WinAuth) and that he gets **all** roles which he could get due to his membership in multiple AD groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A user's permissions on an object is the union of all permissions paths s/he qualifies for (including any DENY permissions). A quick way to verify is by using the sys.user_token and sys.login_token views as well as the sys.fn_my_permissions function. From an administrative perspective, these work especially well because they are accurate under impersonation (i.e. `execute as login = 'yourDomain\someUser'`).

Comment: Well, but what happens if a Windows user could connect to the database via multiple paths - i.e: the user is member of multiple AD groups, and every group is mapped to a Database user. What happens then?

Comment: Exactly as I said; the user will get all permissions granted to all the groups that s/he is a member of. To make it concrete, let's say that yourDomain\GroupA is granted select on yourDomain\TableA, yourDomain\GroupB is granted select on TableB, and that yourDomain\someUser is a member of both groups. yourDomain\someUser will have select permission on TableA by virtue of membership in GroupA and select permission on TableB by virtue of membership in GroupB.

Comment: Thank you. We did various tests now, checking role membership with the built-in function IS_MEMBER(), and it works as you said.